# xmltype character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle, xmltype

In my stored procedure:

```
 declare
v_xml xmltype;
begin
open v_cur for
Select xmlelement('el',xmlagg(xmlelement('el2'))) from table;
loop
fetch v_cur into v_xml; -- line where the error 

*.....additional logic to parse v_xml*
end loop;
end;
```

I'm getting a "character string buffer too small" error when the record to be fetched into v_xml has a length > 4000. Do you guys have any idea on how to go about this? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't that `be xmlelement("el2")` and similar for `"el"`? How many rows do you have in your table?

Answer (score 3):

If you use `xmlagg()`, you'll have to add `.getclobval()` to the surrounding `xmlelement()` since the char limit is 4000 on `xmlagg()`. Obviously this means you'll be using clobs instead of xmltype but you have no choice, you'll have to cast back to xmltype later if needed. Example below:

```
declare
v_xml clob; -- Use CLOB
begin
open v_cur for
Select xmlelement("el",xmlagg(xmlelement("el2", tab_col))).getclobval() from table; -- add .getclobval()
loop
fetch v_cur into v_xml; -- line where the error 

*.....additional logic to parse v_xml*
end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using old Oracle version? There have been some limitations in past. For me it works with 10 000 000 rows:

```
declare
    v_xml xmltype;
begin
    select xmlelement("el", xmlagg(xmlelement("el2")))
    into v_xml from (select 1 from dual connect by level <= 10000000);
end;
```